# XCode - Adding a external static library in Cocoapods project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am experimenting with the Cocoapods to understand what settings/configurations it does so everything works so smoothly. While doing that one specific case troubling me.

Basically there is a different behaviour between **non cocoapods** projects that uses external libs and **cocoapods** projects that uses external libs.

Both projects and external library can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/tarun-talentica/PodsExperiments).

1) External library libImageFilters.a uses CoreMotion framework. So finally when this library will be included in any app, that app will either include CoreMotion framework or use clang modules so that just by doing **@import CoreMotion;** framework is added. I prefer the second approach and for this in the header file (ImageFilters.h) added below lines

```
#if __has_feature(modules)
@import CoreMotion;
#endif
```

2) AppWithoutPods application just add this external lib and header file. Do the below settings

```
Enable Modules = YES
Link Frameworks Automatically = YES
```

Build the application and everything build fine as CoreMotion Framework is included through header file.

3) AppWithPods application uses AFNetworking as a pod. So install the pods and open workspace. When built with above clang module settings,everything builds fine. Now if I add external lib and header file. Build fails with linker error saying CMMotionManager is referenced from libImageFilters. When CoreMotion is explicitly included it builds fine.

This is where the confusion is. Modules are enabled and frameworks are linked automatically. Basically there is nothing different in both apps except cocoapods.

I checked all the settings for both projects, nothing is different then why build fails? Can someone help me understand this?